# Trying to solve this inequation $x\in [0, 2\pi]$: $\log_{\cos{x}}(1+2\cos{x})+\log_{\cos{x}}(1+\cos{x})>1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, logarithms

My attempt

$$\log_{\cos{x}}(1+2\cos{x})+\log_{\cos{x}}(1+\cos{x})>1$$

If $~~0<\cos{x}<1~~$both logarithms are valid. Rewriting the sum as a product, and notice that $\log_{\cos{x}}\cos{x}=1~$ I have

$$\log_{\cos{x}}(2\cos^2{x+3\cos{x}+1})>\log_{\cos{x}}\cos{x}$$

$$ 2\cos^2{x+3\cos{x}+1}<\cos{x}$$

$$2\cos^2{x}+2\cos{x}+1<0$$

But $~2\cos^2{x}+2\cos{x}+1~$ is always $>0$.

This inequation have solutions, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Nothing.............

Comment: In my book the solution is $\dfrac{\pi}{3}<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}~or~\dfrac{3\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$

Comment: Perhaps my book is wrong